# Posting image files to mediafire's upload resource using Android Asynchronous Http Client

Tags: android, post, asynchronous

I am trying to upload files from an Android application to Mediafire using their upload API resource. Also, I am using  [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) through out the app to handle the REST calls.

**Problem:**
The upload fails because of Mediafire returns code **-99**, *"[-99 : Missing or invalid session token](https://www.mediafire.com/developers/upload.php#upload)"*.
I'm passing session_token along with 3 other parameters including the image file.

**Here is the POST call:**

```
RequestParams upload_params = new RequestParams();
File myFile = new File(image.getPath());
try {
    upload_params.put("filename", myFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
}
upload_params.put("session_token", session_token);
upload_params.put("uploadkey", MyConstants.MEDIA_FOLDER_KEY);
upload_params.put("response_format", MyConstants.MEDIA_RESPONSE_FORMAT);
Log.d("PARAMS: ", upload_params.toString());

client.post(MyConstants.MEDIA_BASE_URL + MyConstants.MEDIA_UPLOAD, upload_params, new    JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        String response_string = new String(response);
        Log.d("RESPONSE: ", response_string);
        Log.d("SESSION_TOKEN: ", session_token);
        Log.d("STATUS CODE: ", Integer.toString(statusCode));
        for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            Log.d("Header " + i + ": ", headers[i].toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
    }
});
```

I don't know why but I think my session_token, uploadkey and response_format are not being sent because when I look at the logcat I see the response I get back from Mediafire is in XML.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after countless hours of debugging (3 days worth) that lead no where I finally figured out why the upload wouldn't go through.

Basically Mediafire requires only the file as the POST parameter. It expects the session_token, uploadkey and other parameters as GET.

**I changed my upload_params and POST request to the following to get it working:**

```
RequestParams upload_params = new RequestParams();
File myFile = new File(image.getPath());
try {
    upload_params.put("filename", myFile);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
}
client.post(MyConstants.MEDIA_BASE_URL + MyConstants.MEDIA_UPLOAD +
            "?session_token=my_session_token" +
            "&uploadkey=" + MyConstants.MEDIA_FOLDER_KEY +
            "&response_format=" + MyConstants.MEDIA_RESPONSE_FORMAT), 
            upload_params, 
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        Log.d("RESPONSE: ", new String(response));
        Log.d("SESSION_TOKEN: ", session_token);
        Log.d("STATUS CODE: ", Integer.toString(statusCode));
        for(int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            Log.d("Header " + i + ": ", headers[i].toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
    }
});
```